# Getting questions from SQLite Android

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist

I am trying to make a multiple answer quiz. I followed this website: 
[Simple Quiz Game](http://www.developerfeed.com/simple-quiz-game-andriod)

In the Multiple Activity, I add this:

```
    QuestionsDbHelper db = new QuestionsDbHelper(this);
    questionsList = db.getAllQuestions();
    currentQuestion=questionsList.get(questionId);
```

As you can see on the last line I get this error. In the QuestionsDbHelper, I have added the questions, but still cannot get them display on the Activity.
I have described the Activity in the Manifest file. 
What I can understand from the Debug is that my Array is empty, but I have inserted the list of questions.

Any idea?

```
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
            at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
            at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
            at com.game.mlm.q2game.MultipleMode.onCreate(MultipleMode.java:36)
```

I am posting my code without onCreate and onUpgrade, because they are pretty basic.
Here is my code of QuestionsDbhelper:

```
public void addQuestions(Questions question){
    Log.d("add Questions" , question.toString());

 //   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_QUESTION, question.getQuestion());
    values.put(KEY_ANSWER, question.getAnswer());
    values.put(KEY_FBUTTON, question.getFirstButton());
    values.put(KEY_SBUTTON, question.getSecondButton());
    values.put(KEY_THBUTTON, question.getThirdButton());

    dbase.insert(TABLE_QUESTIONS, null, values);


}
public List<Questions> getAllQuestions(){
    List<Questions> questionsList = new ArrayList<Questions>();
   //SELECT ALL FROM QUERY
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_QUESTIONS;
    dbase= this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    //LOOPING THROUGH ALL ROWS AND ADDING TO LIST
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Questions question = new Questions();
            question.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            question.setQuestion(cursor.getString(1));
            question.setAnswer(cursor.getString(2));
            question.setFirstButton(cursor.getString(3));
            question.setSecondButton(cursor.getString(4));
            question.setThirdButton(cursor.getString(5));
            questionsList.add(question);
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    Log.d( "getAllQuestions()", questionsList.toString() );
    return questionsList;
}
public int rowcount() {
    int row = 0;
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_QUESTIONS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    row = cursor.getCount();
    //  cursor.close();
    return row;
}
```

Comment: `Any idea?` The ArrayList is empty (possibly the query returned an empty result set).

Comment: can you include the code for `QuestionsDbHelper`

Comment: Print the Query in Logcat and run it on SQLite browser. May be your query is wrong.

Comment: EpicPandaForce, I have added my QuestionsDbHelper, still the list is 0

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the questionId is correct? You may have no data for the questionId that you use

Comment: Post this as comment and not as an answer.

Comment: I wasn't allowed to post a comment

Answer (score 0):

Check first the rowCount returns from your DB.
IF yes then move Cursor to first Position using

```
 cursor.moveToFirst();
```

Comment: I have the cursor as you can see, when I debug I can see that the questionList size =0;

Answer (score 0):

use these line in your `getAllQuestions()` method from your `QuestionsDbHelper class`.

```
String Query = "select * from <table name>";
db = openDataBase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(Query, null);
// Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Cursor Length: " + cursor.getCount());
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
<Get all data from table>
}
```